# OpenX Passing Hidden Value for Session ID in URL

Tags: html, session-variables, session-cookies, openx

I need help with this.  Using OpenX, I need to be able to pass a URL link to a page that has a random session ID.  The banner and link are behind a secured login and every user that logs in will get a random session ID.  I need to add that random session ID to the URL string somehow.  I think this can be done is the JS code, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

This is the JS code that resides on the page where the banner/link will be called:

```
                                        <script type='text/javascript'><!--//<![CDATA[
      var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://my-website.com/adserver/www/delivery/ajs.php':'http://my-website.com/adserver/www/delivery/ajs.php');
     var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
     if (!document.MAX_used) document.MAX_used = ',';
     document.write ("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript' src='"+m3_u);
     document.write ("?zoneid=6");
     document.write ('&amp;cb=' + m3_r);
     if (document.MAX_used != ',') document.write ("&amp;exclude=" + document.MAX_used);
     document.write (document.charset ? '&amp;charset='+document.charset : (document.characterSet ? '&amp;charset='+document.characterSet : ''));
     document.write ("&amp;loc=" + escape(window.location));
     if (document.referrer) document.write ("&amp;referer=" + escape(document.referrer));
     if (document.context) document.write ("&context=" + escape(document.context));
     if (document.mmm_fo) document.write ("&amp;mmm_fo=1");
     document.write ("'><\/scr"+"ipt>");
    //]]>--></script><noscript>
<a href='http://my-website.com/adserver/www/delivery/ck.php?      n=ab9755b8&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE' target='_blank'>
<img src='http://my-website.com/adserver/www/delivery/avw.php?  zoneid=6&amp;cb=INSERT_RANDOM_NUMBER_HERE&amp;n=ab9755b8' border='0' alt='' /></a></noscript>
```

---

My Url that I need to add within the adserver has to start with http://XXXXX.com

The hidden value is name="SESSIONTAB"

Any idea how I can include the session id/cookie?

Thanks
Vicky

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work if I add it?

document.getElementById('SESSIONTAB').value = window.location.href;

Remember, the SESSIONTAB is an unknown value and is only known once a user logs into the site where the ad will be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In case anyone else needs this:  I needed to append the URL with a session id.  Mine is actually called Sessiontab.  Where the zone is defined in the JS code, I added this to it:
    &sessiontab=" + document.querySelector('[name="SESSIONTAB"]').value);

So this is what it would look like:

```
document.write ("?zoneid=6&sessiontab=" + document.querySelector('[name="SESSIONTAB"]').value);
```

On the adserver where I enter the information for the banner, I needed to add a variable to the URL.  It looks like this:

```
&sessiontab={sessiontab}
```

I used ampersand, because I already used a ? in the string.